# How can you stream a JSON file in Node.js and interpret it as JSON?

Tags: json, node.js, buffer, fs

I have a JSON file that I want to use in a Node.js script. I want to pass the json and then the script to parse it. I tried using `fs.readFileSync(filename)`, but that returns a buffer. How can I convert that back to JSON so that I can parse it?

Comment: `require('filename.json')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read it from a buffer, you can convert it with `JSON.parse()`.

```
> var fs = require('fs');
undefined
> a=fs.readFileSync('a.json');
<Buffer 7b 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 22 67 6c 6f 73 73 61 72 79 22 ...>
> JSON.parse(a);
{ glossary:
   { title: 'example glossary',
     GlossDiv: { title: 'S', GlossList: [Object] } } }
```

File must be a valid JSON.

You can also do `require` to directly load the JSON.

```
> var a=require('a.json');
undefined
> a
{ glossary:
   { title: 'example glossary',
     GlossDiv: { title: 'S', GlossList: [Object] } } }
```

By default require checks inside `node_modules` folder inside current directory not the current folder. So you should give the path.